# Apache rewrite rule to redirect a URL with parameters to a URL without parameters

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I want to go from:

```
 www.website.com/directory/results?category=10&dir=asc
```

to

```
 www.website.com/staticfile.html
```

I tried the following and it doesn't seem to catch:

```
 RewriteRule "^directory\/results\?category=10&dir=asc" "\/staticfile\.html" [R, L]
```

I can get it to redirect using:

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "^directory\/results" [NC]
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING] category=10&dir=asc
 RewriteRule (.*) "\/staticfile\.html"
```

But then it appends the parameters after `html` in the last example.

Comment: Interestingly, this question is not actually answered in the canonical question/answer

Answer (score 3):

```
  RewriteRule (.*) /staticfile.html?
```

Per the Apache [`RewriteRule` documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule),

> By default, the query string is passed through unchanged. * * * * *  When you want to erase an existing query string, end the substitution string with just a question mark.

Comment: Yep found out that Apache 2.2 does not make use of the QSD flag. In Apache 2.4 this flag is available to shut off the default Apache rewrite behavior of automatically appending query parameters from the old to the new URL.

My configuration looks like this and it works:
          RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} category=10&dir=asc&order=name&format=165
          RewriteRule (.*) "\/4k-ultra-hd\.html?" [R,L]

Comment: QSD is a little different - it is when you want to add a get rid of an existing query string in favor of a replacement. You just need the ? with nothing following for your setup.

Comment: @brenguy - BTW, why are you trying to use regular expression syntax in the Substition string? The RewriteRule substition string is plain text, exept for inclusion of back-references, server-variables, and mapping-function calls, all of which have a speficied(not regular expression) syntax

Comment: If i am understanding the question correctly... are you asking me why I am specifying rewriteconditions or why am I using (.*)?

Comment: @brenguy - I am asking about the formating you use for the substitution string (the `"\/4k-ultra-hd\.html?"` part). It looks like you are writing this as if it was regular expression, which it is not. See the Apache RewriteRule [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) for what may be included in the substitution string. It should probably be just `/4k-ultra-hd.html?` (i.e., no escape, quotes) as suggested in my answer.